# How to get flask form field value into Jijnja2 URL in HTML

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am new to Flask. I want to pass  flask_mongoengine.wtf field value to jijnja URL into HTML.
There is my code. I want to pass **{{ form.from_time_filter }}** form field value to the  **formtime='{{form.from_time_filter}}'**  How i can do it?

```
{% macro render_pagination(page, endpoint ) %}
<div class=pagination>
    {%- for page in posts.iter_pages() %}
    {% if page %}
    {% if page != posts.page %}
    <a href="{{ url_for(endpoint, page=page, formtime='{{form.from_time_filter}}', totime='2020-01-01T23:59', word='Զավենը' ) }}"> {{ page }}</a>
    {% else %}
    <strong>{{ page }}</strong>
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    <span class=ellipsis>…</span>
    {% endif %}
    {%- endfor %}
</div>
{% endmacro %}
{{ render_pagination(posts, 'test_list') }}

<form  method="POST">
    {{ form.from_time_filter.label }} {{ form.from_time_filter }}
    {{ form.to_time_filter.label }} {{ form.to_time_filter }}
    {{ form.incon_filter.label }} {{ form.incon_filter }}
    {{ form.wordtype_filter.label }} {{ form.wordtype_filter }}
    <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help but I'll try to give an answer.

I am using a form to handle searches on my flask based website, the code for the form looks as follows:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" class="form-inline" id="search-form" method="get" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search" type="text" value="{% if search %}{{ search }}{% endif %}">
              </div>
            </form>
```

The python code that then handles the input looks as follows:

```py
def get_entries(offset=0, per_page=5, table=""):  # Used in Index
    search_query = request.args.get('q')
    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
    if search_query:
        entries = table.search(search_query).where(table.published == True).order_by(table.timestamp.desc()).paginate(page, per_page)
        print(entries)
    else:
        entries = table.select().where(table.published == True).order_by(table.timestamp.desc()).paginate(page, per_page)
        print(entries)
    return entries[offset: offset + per_page]
```

When my search form is used it redirects to the /index page, the /index page then checks if there is a value with the name 'q' (this name is specified in the input tag using name="q") if there is, the URL will look like this:
[image: search for iframe]
when I search for "iframe".

And just in case you need it this is what my route for /index looks like:

```py
@app.route('/')  # For browsing and searching up blog entries
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    table = Entry

    pagination_entry = get_entries(table=table)

    pagination = get_pagination_entries(table=table) 

    return render_template('index.html', pagination=pagination, pagination_entry=pagination_entry)
```